# How to clear dropzone-previews?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

We're using dropzone.js to upload files to the server.  It's working, mostly, except for a minor visual thing.

When the user uploads one or more files, preview elements are added to the dropzone-previews list. We're  listing to "addedfile", and displaying information about the uploaded files in a datatable.

If the user uploads more files, these also are added to the dropzone-previews list, and we also add information about them to our datatable.

The problem is that the dropzone-previews list grows indefinitely, for no good purpose.

We want the list, to show the success or failure of each file upload, but we'd like to clear out the list at the start of every upload.  That is, if the user uploads three files, we'd want to see three files in the list. And if the user then uploaded two files, we'd like to see the previews for the first three to be removed, and then the two new uploaded files displayed.

This would be simple, if there was an event that fired prior to the first file upload, but from what I can see, "addedfile" is the first event that always fires, but it fires for each file, and it fires after the preview has been added to the list.

At this point, the only thing I can think of to do is to tag every `<li>` with a custom class in the "complete" event, and then to clear every `<li>` with that event in "addedfile".  I think that would work, but it seems rather round-about, and I'm wondering if I've missed seeing an easier way to do this.

Comment: Looking at the docs, `processingmultiple` looks like a promising event. It seems to fire when multiple files start uploading. If that doesn't work, the steps you outlined shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: What I would like is a single event that fires before any of the individual files are processed, whether a single file is being uploaded or multiples. That doesn't seem to exist. My work-around is ugly, but it seems to be working.